# Installation of pendant lite

Tags: electrical

In our new home the ceiling is wired for a pendant light, but the electrician did not install the light.  Having some experience from helping my late electrician father, I have installed several wall and pendant lights.

The wiring in the ceiling did not have red wire connectors on the ends of the white, black and copper wires. However, on other lights left uninstalled the red wire connectors were on the ends of the wires.

The light has been installed, but it won't come on.  Would the electrician have left something unconnected for some reason?

Answer (score 2):

You may have tried this already but your first step is to use a circuit tester to make sure you have power coming to the white and black wires.

If not, your next step is to walk backwards from the light to troubleshoot. If you made the correct connections at the light then go to the switch and verify that the switch is indeed wired to the line the light is on assuming you know the correct switch to that pendant.

Turn off the breaker to that circuit and unscrew the cover, you may have to also unscrew the switch to move it out of the way in order to see if the pendent wire is connected or not.

Chances are that the electrician has the wire in place but not actually wired to the switch. If it is wired to the switch. The next step would be to check the electrical panel to see if the breaker for this circuit is tripped and/or wired.

If all checks out then you can try to trace the circuit and hope to find the fault.